# How do I run the create method when accessing the `new` path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Having an activation URL which is sent via email, the url is going to redirect to the route's `new` path. How would I go about triggering the `create` method when the user goes to that link?

Alternatively, how do I implement a button in that view that when clicked, it runs the create method?

Just looking for the general way of achieving this.

Comment: Hi, it would be useful if you share your controller code, as well as your email template, to see what you are working with.

Comment: I would just like to know in general how would one go about doing this

Comment: well does your create require any parameters? if so, where do they come from if a record is supposed to be created upon a click in an email? You should show some research effort in order people can help solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it goes to `new` path, you can do whatever you would like to do, and at the end, the new page will be rendered by default. You can as easily trigger a `create` method as any other method in your controller code, but that wouldn't be a best practice.

You can create a custom method that takes care of the creating stuff, and then that method will redirect you to the new method. One functionality per method makes more sense than the two functionalities in one method.

Comment: So basically create a method where I do what I wanted to do on `create` and call it inside the `new` method? Or just do the whole process inside the `new` method?

Comment: You can make a custom method, say `activate` that creates the user. And after that, the `activate` method redirects you to the `new` method.